# Is it possible to generate unique ID for each tab?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, session, browser-tab

Is it possible to generate unique ID for each browser tab and send it every time I submit or click an AJAX link on the page.
I want to use this ID for session control.

or Are there any other solution for multiple tab session control other than keep an id in url?

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE SITUATION:**
I have a document based form page which have some popup and ajax link to update data that i kept in session.
Then if user open this form in multiple tab how can I distinct a page from each other?

Comment: What do you want to do?

Answer (score 2):

Just don't, please.

`ASP.NET MVC` is made to be **stateless**.

You may think you need state but you really don't. If you'll tell us more about your situation we'll sure come up with ideas how it can be done without session.

If you want to pass information between clients, real-time even, you can look into [SignarR](http://signalr.net/).

Comment: I wonder where does it say this question is about ASP.NET MVC. I also have this problem on a NOT ASP.NET MVC page and I'd like to knwo how to solve it. Please..